# Probability that the first time that $N_t = n$ is at $t = s$?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Suppose that $N_t$ is a Poisson process, so that 
$$f(t, n) := P\{N_t = n\} = \frac{e^{-\lambda t} (\lambda t)^n}{n!}.$$

How do I compute the density of the following event 
$$S_n = \inf \{t \geq 0 : N_t = n\}?$$

One thing I know is $\{S_n = s\}$ is the same as $\{N_s = n \land N_t < n, \forall t < s\}$. Can someone help me?

Comment: Assuming no typos, there are more than a couple of things that are not quite correct in your attempt (including how you frame the question). Do you want people to help fix the existing line of thoughts, or are you willing to start over?

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I would be interested in fixing the existing line of thoughts.

Comment: Why do you think that $\{N_s=n\wedge N_t<n,\forall t<s\}$ the same as $\{N_s=n,N_{s-1}<n\}$? It might even be so that $s<1$ so that $N_{s-1}$ is not defined.

Comment: @drhab you're right, I'm realizing now that $S_n$ has density, not a mass function, so among other things $S_n = \inf\{t \geq 0 : N_t = n\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $\delta\in(0,s)$ we have:$$S_n=s\implies N_s-N_{s-\delta}>0$$

so that: $$P(S_n=s)\leq P(N_s-N_{s-\delta}>0)=1-P(N_s-N_{s-\delta}=0)=1-e^{-\lambda\delta}$$

Let $\delta$ approach to $0$ and draw conclusions.

---

**addendum** (because of update of question)

$$P(S_n>t)=P(N_t<n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}$$

This enables you to find the CDF and (by differentiating) also the PDF of $S_n$

---

**extra info** (nice to know about Poisson processes).

If $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are iid with exponential distribution equipped with parameter $\lambda$ then they "induce" a Poisson process $N_t$ with rate $\lambda$.

This by stating that $S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$ and defining:

$$N_t:=|\{k\in\mathbb N\mid S_k\leq t\}|$$

So the density of $S_n$ could also be found on base of $S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$.

Comment: what you're saying doesn't make sense. You're really saying that the probability is 0?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying. Why does it not make sense? Be aware of the fact that $S_n$ can take *all* values in $(0,\infty)$. It is random variable with continuous distribution. That gives directly $P(S_n=s)=0$ for every $s$.

Comment: yes, you're right. How do I solve this, then?

Comment: You find a solution for it in my answer. It is a valid proof for $P(S_n=s)=0$.

Comment: I revised my question so that it is now asking about density. how do I compute that?

Comment: I have edited my answer.